# Execution of remaining command in build phase if one of the command fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In buildspec I have various commmand in the build phase each of the command are independent of each other but major problem is if one of the command fail to execute remaining command do not execute . I want to execute all the command regardless of the previous command fail or pass

Answer (score 0):

This is the phase transition that AWS CodeBuild builds go through: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases.

If your build command does not fail in the "pre_build" or earlier phases, then your commands specified in subsequent phases will still be run.

You can also use the finally sub-phase to always execute a particular command(s), even when a phase fails. More details in the sample at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-example